# What is the meaning of asterisk, backslash, colon and two in (*\:2)?

Tags: bash, expansion

What is the meaning of following `ls` command?

```
ls -l *\:2,*T
```

- `ls` = list
- `-l` = long (list)
- `*T` probably means `T` at the end

But what about that `*\:2` and the comma?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`*\:2,*T` is the glob pattern of files to list. To understand it, we need to remember a few things:

- `:` has to be escaped in the shell, becoming `\:`
- File names can easily contain commas

So `*\:2,*T` would e.g. match a file called `TranscationNumber:2,EventType:XYT`

**EDIT**

From the comments, the necessity (or not) of escaping the `:` needs a few words: It is **not** strictly necessary to escape the `:` sign, but bash itself suggests it when autocompleting.

Comment: Thank you, both Eugen and HBruijn. I suspected some complicated globbing pattern, but actually it should just match the colon and the comma, which I did not think of when working with files. Now, the command totally makes sense: list all email files in the Maildir directories, which are marked as "Deleted" (T). Btw. The number 2 means Maildir in version 2 (cf https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir).

Comment: Since when does `:` have to be escaped?

Comment: `:` doesn't need to be escaped. It is only special in specific circumstances (when used as a command), not in glob patterns. The `\:` is equivalent to `:`, escaping makes no difference.

Comment: @terdon I was wondering in which case it would be interesting to have `\:` as a command, and found out that `bash` still seems to parse `\:` as the NOP command. See [this ideone](http://ideone.com/U4GWei). I guess it was different in older versions of bash or other shells?

Comment: @Barmar Edited my answer, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Aaron, it's not *exactly* no-op: the shell will still process variable substitutions, particularly the assignment variety (i.e. to set default values): `unset var; : ${var:=x}; echo $var`

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't expect `\:` to protect if from being recognized as a command since that is another common construct used, for example, to [ignore aliases](https://askubuntu.com/a/525242/85695). On the other hand, tab completion on a file whose name has a `:` results in `\:`. I don't know why that would happen but I would guess that it is historical and that older shells would choke on it. I tested on bash, dash, tcsh and ksh and all of them had no issue dealing with `:`. Presumably, some older shells did.

Comment: @terdon thanks, I didn't know about that use of backslash, I would have used `command` or `builtin` to achieve the same effect. There's definitely something weird with the auto-completion : I've tested with bash on both a Cygwin and an RHEL and got some weird behaviors, including the one you mention, the inability to complete just after the `:` or even worse, completion proposals based only on the part following the `:` (i.e. completion after `test:te` proposing every file starting with `te`). Looks like escaping them can be a good idea.

Comment: @terdon & @Aaron The colon `:` is part of the default values for the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` environment variable. In Bash autocompletion those characters are used as word separators by the read line library and a file-name containing a colon should of course be a single word. Hence the reason that bash autocompletion requires the colon to be escaped, although otherwise it is "*mostly*" not a special character...

Answer (score 14):

List all files that match the wildcard pattern `*:2,*T`

There the wildcard `*` matches anything (any number of all possible characters)
`:2,` are characters that need to be present in the file/directory names.
The colon `:` is a special character that needs to be escaped, hence the form of `\:2,`.
The file/directory names need to end with a `T`.

File names that would match would be

```
:2,T
a:2,T
a:2,bT
abbY-$fafaf:2,<hskjhsgdfhjk>T
```

Comment: There's nothing special about :, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Kevin bash auto-completion automatically escapes the colon in file/directory name patterns, because is included in the list of `COMP_WORDBREAK` environment values that get set by default.  - So it is indeed not an actual special character, but when you use autocompletion on the commandline and want/need to match filenames with a colon , it does need to be escaped.

Answer (score 9):

As others have noted, this will list in long format, files containing `:2`, and ending in `T`

This looks like a search in a Maildir folder for files that were deleted  (trashed). However, for robustness it should have had another `*` at the end, though. New flags with a later alphabetical position could be added, and Dovecot for instance adds another field with the file size at the end.

- https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html